Dependent Pivot Drop Downs
I am hoping someone can help. My search thus far has yielded no results, and I refuse to think this hasn't been released yet.
I have a Pivot of an extremely large set of data. In the filters is a hierarchy of customers, at International, National, Line of Business and Branch levels. What I am looking to achieve in an Excel pivot table, is what I am easily able to achieve in other software, such as Power BI for example.
When I select lets say GB for the International level, then only GB National, LOB, and Branches show, if I was to filter that down further, then the other filters auto adjust.
Outside of Pivots this is a simple set up with a dependent drop down structure. Is there a way of doing this in a Pivot?
